# Jquery datepicker - only every second click event fires

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a page with a jqueryui datepicker control.
On each day selection, I post with ajax to a web method to do some server side data population to fill the drop down box which is beneath the calendar control.

I used this code for two pages already, first works perfect, but am having issues with this one.
The first time I select a date, the event fires fine, second time nothing happens, then the next click works fine again. So the event only fires on every second click, be it the same date or a different date.
I added an  input control to capture date selection, which works fine on each select.

What bugs me now is, If I add an alert inside my select jquery function, it fires every time, take it out and I have this issue again.

Thanks

Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="Site.Master" CodeBehind="calendartest.aspx.cs"  Inherits="Test.calendartest" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                onSelect: function(dateStr, inst) {

                    document.getElementById('<%= hSelectedDate.ClientID %>').value = dateStr;
                    var hubid = 2; 

                    $('#<%=ddlAvailableTimes.ClientID %>').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Loading...</option>');

                    $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "UserCP.aspx/PopulateAvailableTimeSlots",
                            data: ("{date:'" + dateStr + "', hubid:'" + hubid + "'}"),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: OnTimeSlotsPopulated
                        });

                    $("#datepicker_value").val(dateStr);
                }
            });
        });

        function OnTimeSlotsPopulated(response) {
            PopulateControl(response.d, $("#<%=ddlAvailableTimes.ClientID %>"));
        }

        function PopulateControl(list, control) {
            if (list.length > 0) {
                control.removeAttr("disabled");
                control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">--Select Time Slot--</option>');
                $.each(list, function() {
                    control.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#<%=ddlAvailableTimes.ClientID%>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">--No Slots Available--<option>');
            }
        }
    </script>

    <input id="hSelectedDate" type="hidden" value="" runat="server" />
    <input id="hfHub" type="hidden" value="" runat="server" />
    <table style="width: 290px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
        align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <div id="datepicker">
                </div>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAvailableTimes" runat="server"  Width="192px" Enabled="false">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select Time Slot--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>             
                    <input id="datepicker_value" />
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Server Side:

```
public partial class calendartest : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static ArrayList PopulateAvailableTimeSlots(string date, string hubid)
    {
      ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
      //Do stuff here
      return list;
    }
  }
```

HTML Output:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <link href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="themes/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="themes/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="calendartest.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                onSelect: function(dateStr, inst) {
                    document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_hSelectedDate').value = dateStr;
                    var hubid = 2; 
                    $('#ctl00_MainContent_ddlAvailableTimes').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Loading...</option>');

                    $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "UserCP.aspx/PopulateAvailableTimeSlots",
                            data: ("{date:'" + dateStr + "', hubid:'" + hubid + "'}"),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: OnTimeSlotsPopulated
                        });
                    $("#datepicker_value").val(dateStr);
                }
            });
        });

        function OnTimeSlotsPopulated(response) {
            PopulateControl(response.d, $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlAvailableTimes"));
        }

        function PopulateControl(list, control) {
            if (list.length > 0) {
                control.removeAttr("disabled");
                control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">--Select Time Slot--</option>');
                $.each(list, function() {
                    control.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlAvailableTimes").attr("disabled", "disabled");

                control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">--No Slots Available--<option>');
            }
        }
    </script>

    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$hSelectedDate" type="hidden" id="ctl00_MainContent_hSelectedDate" />
    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$hfHub" type="hidden" id="ctl00_MainContent_hfHub" />

    <table style="width: 290px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <div id="datepicker">
                </div>
                <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlAvailableTimes" id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlAvailableTimes" disabled="disabled" style="width:192px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="0">--Select Time Slot--</option>
                </select>             
                    <input id="datepicker_value" />
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include only the code pertinent to the question - that's a huge amount of code for us to look through.

Comment: Adding the alert might act like a pause. Have you checked if the events fire like intented if you wait 2-3 seconds between click?

Comment: @Utkanos: Apologies, I just wasnt sure what exactly to post. SO I posted the basic design of my page as I dunno if the error could be in my js or design of my page.

Comment: @ThomAS:Just tried it, waiting a few seconds does not change anything, still the same issue.

Comment: Could you please post the resulting html which is generated by above code.

Comment: @ThomAS: Which part of the code would you want, there are over a thousand lines of code.

Comment: The smallest subset from your output which still behaves as explained in your original posting.

Comment: @ThomAS: I added the popup dialog html out code. I don't understand howcome there is not any code for the datepicker though. As that is where i'm having this issue. I'm using the jquery datepicker http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Argh, found the issue. Had this in my server side code:
            protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                  base.OnLoad(e);                  
            }

Removing this solved the issue.

Comment: Never mind, stopped working properly again, same issue.

Comment: I created a test page to only work on this issue. Updated the question description and code accordingly.

Comment: With your html output, a local test site and omitting the ajax request  i see the following result: OnTimeSlotsPopulated is called on every click and PopulateControl is called on every click. Therefore i might suspect the cause of the behavior you are seeing is in server side call. Can you verify above behavior when you call the ajax methode? Have a look at the javascript call stack in your favorite debugger.

Comment: @ThomAS yes, on each click, I make an ajax call, which on success calls the OnTimeSlotsPopulated function, which calls the PopulateControl function to populate the control with the web method result.
I put a breakpoint in the web method and seems that breakpoint gets hit on every click, but seems the ddlAvailableTimes text only changes on every second click. 
On each click the dropdown is supposed to show the "loading" text and then either "select a timeslot" or no slots available" text depending on the web method result.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint in "PopulateControl" and "OnTimeSlotsPopulated" and see what executes and what not. In the test scenario the code executes like you intent it to.

Comment: @ThomAS Breakpoints in my javascript are not being hit, I have cleared the "disable script debugging" checkbox in my browser settings. But these methods do get hit everytime in anycase, my data populates fine. The main issue is that the the dropdown boxes text is not being updated on each click. WHile im quering the database, I want the dropdown list to to disable and show the text "Loading...", once I get the result, if there are records, enable the dropdown again, and change the text to "select a time slot", if no records, keep drop down box disabled and change text to "No slots available".

Comment: Apologies if my explanation isnt clear, I'm trying really hard to explain the basic issue I have on hand, and seems I have this issue with all my jquery functions on my site. Server side code runs fine, issue is the client UI not updating on each click, change or whichever event I call from client side.

Comment: Since I can´t reproduce the error here I have to give up on this issue. I strongly believe that debugging your client side code with a propper debugger (e.g Google Chrome) will give you some information to use. Questions that might be interesting to know: Does ("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlAvailableTimes") match on every click? Is the variable "control" available in PopulateControl at every click?  What happens if you just do something totally different instead of changing the options in the select e.g changing colors. Does this work? Thats really something you have to investigate in.