# jQuery UI DatePicker only trickers validation every second time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, validation, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have uploaded a simple application where you can have the same experience as I am having with the 
DatePicker jQuery UI:
**DatePickerValidationMvc**: [**http://sdrv.ms/17tS25J**](http://sdrv.ms/17tS25J)

I am using jQuery UI DatePicker in my UI, the markup and script looks like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ExpireDateTime, new { id = "expiration-date", @Value = Model.ExpireDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#expiration-date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
    });
</script>
```

I am using **Remote validation** and my attribute on the model looks like this:

```
[Remote("IsDateBetweenDateRangeAction", "Home", HttpMethod = "POST")]
```

I am just using the default MVC 4 template from Visual Studio.
Thus I am referencing these scripts:

**jquery-1.8.2.js
jquery-ui-1.8.24.js**

The **markup** being generated looks like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input Value="13-09-2015" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Expiration Date (DD-MM-YYYY) must be a date." data-val-remote="&#39;Expiration Date (DD-MM-YYYY)&#39; is invalid." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.ExpireDateTime" data-val-remote-type="POST" data-val-remote-url="/Home/IsDateBetweenDateRangeAction" data-val-required="The Expiration Date (DD-MM-YYYY) field is required." id="expiration-date" name="ExpireDateTime" type="text" value="13-09-2015 09:57:14" /><br />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ExpireDateTime" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

**The funny thing is that when I change the date with the DatePicker validation is only trickered every 2 time.**

It seems I am not the only one having had this experience:
[**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341110/jquery-datepicker-only-every-second-click-event-fires**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341110/jquery-datepicker-only-every-second-click-event-fires)

**Anyone knows how to have my validation method called every time the date is changed and not only every second time?**

I have uploaded a simple application where you can have the same experience as I am having with the 
DatePicker jQuery UI:
DatePickerValidationMvc: **http://sdrv.ms/17tS25J**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to the above problem. A function executing on the onClose event was the answer:

```
$(function () {
    $("#expiration-date").datepicker({

        onClose: function () {
            $("#register-imei-form").validate().element("#expiration-date");
        }

    });
});
```

I found the answer in this thread:
[jQuery UI Datepicker with altfields: Validation not firing when it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834859/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-altfields-validation-not-firing-when-it-should?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Add the JS files to your page or PartialView to add **client** **validation** in MVC. they should be in the Scripts folder.

MSDN info:

*Enabling Client-Side Validation
To enable client-side validation in ASP.NET MVC 3, you must set two flags and you must include three JavaScript files.
Open the application's Web.config file. Verify that ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled are set to true in the application settings. The following fragment from the root Web.config file shows the correct settings:*

```
 <appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
 </appSettings>
```

AND

```
<head>
  <title>@View.Title</title>
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Agnakor, but my solution was already doing the things you mention. Anyway I found a solution to the problem in handling the onClose event, of the DatePicker :)

Comment: you never mentioned that you had some events attached... but im glad your problem is solved.

Comment: Hi Agnakor, well I actually was not handling any events at first, I think, but as it turned out, to handle the onClose event solved the problem. Enjoy the spring and the code ;)